# Dependent multiselect dropdown using chosen and select2 plugins

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, multi-select

This is the code I have written in **View** :

```
   <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" style=" margin-top: 14px; ">Domains&nbsp;<font size="3" color="red">*</font></label>
        <br />

        <div class="col-sm-4" style="width:50%;">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedDomains, Model.AllDomains,
         new { @class = "chosen", multiple = "multiple", id = "drpDomains", style = "width: 350px;",onchange="FillDomain();" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" style=" margin-top: 14px; ">Domains new categories&nbsp;<font size="3" color="red">*</font></label>
        <br />

        <div class="col-sm-4" style="width:50%;">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedDomainCategories, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
           new { @class = "select2", multiple = "multiple", id = "multidomaincategory", style = "width: 350px;" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link href="~/Scripts/MultiSelect/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

For Domains, I have used Chosen plugin, and for categories, i have used select2 plugin

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(".chosen-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
$(".chosen").chosen().change();
$(".chosen").trigger('liszt:updated');
</script>

<script>
    function FillDomain() {
        $("#drpDomains option[value='']").removeAttr("selected");

        var selectArr = [];
        $('#drpDomains').each(function () {

            selectArr.push($(this).val());
        });
        var a = JSON.stringify(selectArr);

        var reference = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: @Url.Content("~/MyTemplate2/FillIndustry1"), //FillIndustry1 is a method in Controller
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { Domain: a },
            success: function (DomainCategories) {

                $("#multidomaincategory").html("");

                $("#multidomaincategory").removeAttr("selected");
                var s = JSON.stringify(DomainCategories);

                var t = JSON.parse(s);

                for (var key in t) {

                    $("#multidomaincategory").append("<option value=" + t[key]["Value"] + ">" + t[key]["Text"] + "</option>");
                } 

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("failure error" + data);
                var t = window.JSON.parse(data.d);
                alert("failueee" + t);
            }

        });
       //I'm trying to remove all the selected items from dependent dropdown (#multidomaincategory) when all items from Domains(#drpDomains) are cleared

        if ($("#drpDomains").val() == null || $("#drpDomains").val() == "") {

            $("#multidomaincategory").removeAttr("selected");
            $("#multidomaincategory").css('display', 'none');



           }
    }
</script>
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FillIndustry1(string Domain)
    {
        JArray jsonMembersArr = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Domain);//convert SymptomString from json string to array

        ProfessionalTrans objprofessionaltrans = new ProfessionalTrans();
        string listdomains = "";
        foreach (var a in jsonMembersArr)
        {

            listdomains = string.Join(",", a);
        }
        var DomainCategories = objprofessionaltrans.GetDepCategories(listdomains);

        return Json(DomainCategories.ToList());
    }
```

Data Access Layer(Transaction):

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDepCategories(string domains)
    {
 //GetDepCategories method - To get categories based on Domains
        PTS_CommonEntities objentity = new PTS_CommonEntities();
        List<SelectListItem> allskills = new List<SelectListItem>();

        List<GetCatListbasedDomain> catnames = objentity.usp_GetCatListBasedOnDomains(domains).ToList();

        foreach (var it in catnames)
        {
            allskills.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = it.CategoryID.ToString(), Text = it.CategoryName });

        }    

        return allskills.AsEnumerable();
```

### }

When I am clearing(closing) the selected items in Domains, the respective Categories are cleared from list, but not in the text box

Image [Before Clearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhlc6.png)

Image [After Clearing the Domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GRC0.png)

As you can see, the list is being cleared, but the selected items are still being shown in the UI.

Can someone please find out why the items are being displayed even after clearing them???

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to clear the wrong element. `#multidomaincategory` is the select2 list that holds all of the values, there is a dynamic span class that gets rendered to the page right after this element, look at the html that select2 produces in your browser. Try:

```
$('#multidomaincategory').next().find('li').html('');
```

They are cleared from the list because `$("#multidomaincategory").html("");` clears the html of the **list** of categories, not the rendered text elements in the text box.

Although a better way: `$('#multidomaincategory').select2('data', null)`

Comment: Hey @Martin, thanks for answering, but the rendered text elements are not cleared when I use the two lines that you posted. Do you know any other events that can clear the rendered text elements

Comment: @jagadeesh64 Edit the post with the rendered select2 html from the browser in the question.